# Config modification with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Sorry this is a quick one. I am attempting to modify the value of an ssh config file using a simple sed command (as part of a larger script performing a number of functions). I can't seem to figure out why it is not working. Here is the line of the config I am trying to change:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Here is my code:

```
    sed 's/^\(PermitRootLogin\s*.\s*\).*$/\1Yes/' sshd_config
```

So the goal is to replace the 'without-password' with yes. It appears to work except I receive this instead:

```
PermitRootLogin wYes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down the regexp:

```
^\(PermitRootLogin\s*.\s*\).*$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `\(` starts a capture grou
- `PermitRootLogin` matches that directive
- `\s*` matches the longest sequence of spaces after the directive
- `.` matches the first character after the spaces, which is the `w` at the beginning of `without-password`
- `\s*` matches the longest sequence of spaces after the `w`. Since there are no spaces there, it matches the empty string.
- `\)` ends the capture group

All the above gets put into capture group `1`.

- `.*` matches everything after that.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

So capture group `1` contains `PermitRootLogin w`. You then copy that into the replacement, with `Yes` added to it. The result is

```
PermitRootLogin wYes
```

I would just use

```
sed 's/^PermitRootLogin\s.*$/PermitRootLogin Yes/' sshd_config
```

There's no need for a capture group when you don't need to copy any variable match to the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\(PermitRootLogin \).*/\1Yes/' sshd_config
```

Use the `-i` option to edit the file *in place*:

```
sed -i 's/^\(PermitRootLogin \).*/\1Yes/' sshd_config
```

Your pattern was capturing `w` because it's the first character (`.`) after zero or more space (`\s*`) in regex `\s*.`

Comment: I'll accept as correct but I have to wait for 9 minutes. I was posting the answer to my own problem at the same time you posted so it has now delayed